# Feature Vector from an audio signal

Tags: audio, feature-extraction

I want to develop a feature vector from an audio input.

Up to now, I have identified *fundamental frequency, max phonation time, timbre* to be among the key features to be identified.

Can someone please confirm whether it will be possible to extract these features from the audio?

Comment: It's possible. Was that really your question?

Comment: @MarcusMüller well, I want to know whether it is possible to obtain an exact value for each audio sample.

Comment: no. A single sample is just a number. It *can't* have something like a frequency: What is the frequency of $0.4$?

Comment: Things like timbre and fundamental frequency only make sense when considered for a sequence of samples – but I'm not telling you anything you don't know, I guess; I really just try to find out what your *precise* question is.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I meant an audio sample of duration like 20 - 40 ms :)
Not a single sample! Of course it's a sequence of samples.....
Sorry for the bad definition!

Comment: lotsa ways to define *"timbre"*.  ain't just a one-dimensional parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Have a good read of various features that can be extracted from popular audio analysis libraries like librosa: https://librosa.github.io/librosa/feature.html

- Fundamental frequency (F0) can definitely be extracted. This itself a whole subfield, so google and previous SO questions are your best starting point after reading through what a [pitch tracker looks like](http://labrosa.ee.columbia.edu/projects/SAcC/).
- For max phonation time, MFCCs are typically the features computed in the front-end of a speech recognition system, which can give you "phone" sequences and their timing. But this would be a lot of processing as the concept of a "phone" in a speaker-independent sense is quite far from raw audio features one might compute directly on the audio signal (like RMS, ZCR, spectral features, etc)
- For timbre, have a read through Bello's notes: http://www.nyu.edu/classes/bello/MIR_files/timbre.pdf

Good luck!

Comment: Ah! Now that makes better sense! Thanks for the guidance!